# Memo fields showing chinese characters or symbols instead of actual value when records number reach a certain point

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is my first post here and I am a database newbie. I tried to find an answer, but I'm not sure I understand how it applies to my case.

My access program generates a query with different types of fields (Autonumber, shorttext, memo) which is then used to create a report.
It has been working fine until now, but since the DB has grown I run into a problem.

I use the ID (primary key) IN () the where condition to filter the report. I make a long string that get all the id of the selected records:

```
WHERE ID IN (1200,1201,1203,1226,1227,1228,1229,...)
```

When a certain amount of characters in the query is reached (around 4000), I get Chinese characters instead of all the memo fields, and only the memo fields, of the query results (and then in the report).

Is there a limit in the query size? Isn't it 32000 characters?
Why do these characters shows only if I select too many records?

**Is there a substite to IN () that could help me reduce the query lengh or should I completely avoid memo fields?**

EDIT : That's the query (stripped down a little to be readable) :

```
SELECT ObjetsLegislatifs.IDobjet, ObjetsLegislatifs.TitreObjet, ObjetsLegislatifs.ContenuObjet
FROM ObjetsLegislatifs
WHERE IDobjet IN(1200,1201,1203,1226,1227,1228,1229,1230,1231,1232,)
GROUP BY ObjetsLegislatifs.IDobjet, ObjetsLegislatifs.TitreObjet, ObjetsLegislatifs.ContenuObjet
ORDER BY ObjetsLegislatifs.IDobjet;
```

Basicaly, th IDobjet is a autonumber, the "TitreObjet" and "ContenuObjet" are Memos fields.
While IDobjet always shows the proper number, the memo fields start showing chinese when the query is too long, when a certain threshold is reached. I tried with a text field instead in the query and they work fine.

Comment: Well, that's a first... I've never heard it called a "databank" before.  But you'll be better off using a temporary table and `Join`ing to it, rather than making a list of 4000 `In` params.

Comment: You could make multiple requests each of no more than 4000 long and then `UNION` results.

Comment: @RomanBK I have edited your question down a little. What I'm not clear about: what are the 'memo fields of the query results'? What is the data that you are selecting (the first part of the SQL statement)? Please [add  that to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24936779/edit)

Comment: Tanks a lot! I will use a temp table. I find sometimes tiresome that access offer option it can't really handle...

Comment: @JanDoggen I edited the question, I hope it can help others! thanks for your help. Sorry it took so long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing for you to do is create a temporary table (which is a special type of table - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837200(v=office.15).aspx)) with a single `ID` column.

When generating the query, you can then insert your `ID` into this table and join to it instead of using an `IN list`, something like this:

```
select a.*
from table a
INNER JOIN temp_table b ON a.ID = b.ID
```